# Scenario Outline for json in feature with Karate

Tags: karate

Is it possible to use Scenario Outline as in this mode (which is really great!!):

```
Scenario Outline:
* print 'hello <name>'

Examples:
| (read('cats.json')) |
```

but with a json or a list in Background? Ex:

```
Background:
  * json temp = cats_ids (ids that I get from an external job as here [111,222,333...]) 
  or
  * def temp = cats_ids

  Scenario Outline:
  * path id from temp
  * method get
  ...
  Examples:
  | temp |
```

Comment: sorry @Peter Thomas, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please look at `karate.mapWithKey()` explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def temp = karate.mapWithKey(cats_ids, 'id')

Scenario Outline:
* print id
```